# extend class issue when creating new object

Tags: java, inheritance

There's something wrong in my code, but i don't know why. I have two class:

```
public class MyClass extends MySuperClass {
    potected int field1;
    public MyClass() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public int getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }
    public void setField1(int f) {
        this.field1 = f;
    }
}


public class MySuperClass {
    potected int field1, field2;
    public MySuperObject() {
    }

    public int getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }
    public void setField1(int f) {
        this.field1 = f;
    }

    public void setField2(int f) {
        this.field2 = f;
    }

    public int getField2() {
       return this.field2;
    }
}
```

When i create different new MyClass object (i.e. for insert inside an ArrayList) something go wrong:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
while(condidion) {
    MyClass obj = new MyClass();
    obj.setField1(value1);
    obj.setField2(value2);
    list.add(obj);
}
```

If value1 and value2 assume the sequent value

> 1 and 50
>
> 2 and 70
>
> 3 and 80

After my code is executed, my list contains

> 1 and 80
>
> 2 and 80
>
> 3 and 80

It looks like that every time i create new MyClass object, only an instance of MySuperClass it's created (field2 assume the value of last input value).
How can i fix it?

Comment: Where are you getting the `value2` from?

Comment: First of all, you are shadowing field1 which is protected in MySuperClass in MyClass. Why are you doing that? It is not necessary because you could access it directly in MyClass since it is protected.
Secondly, can you please provide a complete code? It should contain also the output - maybe the problem is there...

Comment: Make sure you are entering correct value in the value1 and value2.

Comment: Is the value2 static? Or are the fields in MySuperClass static?
Looks like you haven't copied the code right.

Comment: Are you sure that if you create new object in while loop

Comment: giozh.. Please make sure you have entered the correct values for value2. since there might be a mistake as you are using a loop. Also could you please share your code more elaborately. I mean in a proper way? Because: 
1) you are declaring the field1 protected in the subclass also
2) Your class name is MySuperClass and your constructor is MySuperObject. 
3) Also share the code where you are adding the values to the list

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla yes, you are right! field 2 was static.

i need to declare also field1 in subclass for some implementation reasons

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which you have given. It is working perfectly if you give correct input.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MyClass extends MySuperClass {

protected int field1;

public MyClass() {
    super();
}

@Override
public int getField1() {
    return this.field1;
}

public void setField1(int f) {
    this.field1 = f;
}
```

}
    class MySuperClass {

```
protected int field1, field2;

public MySuperClass() {
}

public int getField1() {
    return this.field1;
}

public void setField1(int f) {
    this.field1 = f;
}

public void setField2(int f) {
    this.field2 = f;
}

public int getField2() {
    return this.field2;
}
```

}

```
public class Tryouts {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;

    ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
    while(i < 3) {
        MyClass obj = new MyClass();
        obj.setField1(40 + i);
        obj.setField2(80+ i);
        list.add(obj);
        i++;
    }

    for (MyClass c : list) {
        System.out.println(c.getField1() + "::" + c.getField2());
    }
}
```

}

```
The output is 
40::80,   41::81,   42::82
```